# Laravel/COmposer install, PDOException when running pipelines on Bitbucket

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, bitbucket

I have a site running on laravel, and when I run the pipelines from bitbucket it goes through composer install, but at the end after installing most packages I get this:

```
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
phpspec/phpspec suggests installing phpspec/nyan-formatters (~1.0 – Adds 
Nyan formatters)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled

[PDOException]         
could not find driver  

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event 
returned with error code 1
```

These pipelines used to pass fine, when looking at version control, but now it's failing and I have no idea how to trace this back. I included some extra lines at the top from the pipelines console, but I think it just involves the last few lines.

Is there a known issue or way to resolve this? I'm coming up empty.

Comment: You're either missing a database driver value in the `config/database.php` for the connection Bitbucket is using, or Bitbucket doesn't have your chosen database driver's plugin installed or activated.

Comment: ok I will check into the database driver value. SHould that config/database.php file be in the vendor folder?

Comment: No, `config/database.php` is part of your application.

Comment: Oh I see it now, thank you. It may be an issue with my ODBC connection